# Separating .js elements/ .js element communication

Tags: javascript, data-structure, architecture

So I have 2 questions regarding the code below:

```js
function goldClick(number){
    gold = gold + number;
    document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = gold;
};


function buyMiner(){
    var minerCostG = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(2.1,miner));
 var minerCostW = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(3.1,miner)); 
    if(gold >= minerCostG){
  if(wood >= minerCostW){        
   miner = miner + 1;                                   
   gold = gold - minerCostG;
   wood = wood - minerCostW;        
   document.getElementById('miner').innerHTML = miner;  
   document.getElementById('gold').innerHTML = gold;
   document.getElementById('wood').innerHTML = wood;       
    }};
    var nextCostMG = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(2.1,miner));       
    document.getElementById('minerCostG').innerHTML = nextCostMG;
 
 var nextCostMW = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(3.1,miner));       
    document.getElementById('minerCostW').innerHTML = nextCostMW; 
};

window.setInterval(function(){
 
 goldClick(miner);
 
}, 1000);
```

Question 1: Is it possible to separate these functions (goldclick, buyminer, window interval,) into their own documents so that if I have say, 50 different XXXXclick functions, and 50 buyXXXX functions and 50 interval functions, I have just 3 .js documents instead of 50.

Question 2: If it is possible to separate them, how would I ensure that they are communicating with each other and variable values are not being confused or sent to the wrong `<span>` in the displaying html.

Comment: Welcome to GameDev stack exchange.
I think your questions should be better moved to / posted on StackOverflow because it is not really game related and more a general programming question.
Regarding your question: 1. it is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file
2: your code should not communicate via HTML. Only the output should be written to HTML. It seems you lack a solid understanding about how javascript works and the concept of scoping. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: So after reading the questions you posted and some of the answers for them this is what I am getting: For the variables to be called throughout my code (js, html) they need to be globally declared first.
Is that correct? @BenediktS.Vogler

Comment: I only have basic knowledge of JS therefore I did not post an answer but commented. I guess they need to be declared global but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it, you can write your code in any files you want and load them in the app load time and share the important data via window variables or via the class constructor.

But i would make it little different, i would create some clases (miner, plumber, whatever) and make them inherit some "base" functions like .buy(), .goldClick(), etc so you can have a common "base class" file and some "specific" class file such a "miner.js", etc...

I made kind of [engine](https://github.com/PRDeving/SGE#another-piece-of-code) that "Loads" any requirements you need, such a node modules in clientside, give it a pick if you want.

I hope this helps.

Comment: is there a technical term for "base" functions. Ir is it just inherited functions? @RDeving

Comment: Yep, where i said "base" i mean a class por función with all the shared actions and variables so you can inherit it